# Ruby Http server in separate thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, http, tcp

I'm using the code found on https://practicingruby.com/articles/implementing-an-http-file-server?u=dc2ab0f9bb to start a simple http server in Ruby.

This code works great. However, the server.accept call and the loop do block up the main thread. I've changed the code to the following:

```
require 'socket' # Provides TCPServer and TCPSocket classes

#start the server thread
server_thread = Thread.start do

    # Initialize a TCPServer object that will listen
    # on localhost:2345 for incoming connections.
    server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2345)

    # loop infinitely
    loop do

      # use a seprate thread, acception multiple incoming connections
      Thread.start(server.accept) do |socket|

          # Read the first line of the request (the Request-Line)
          request = socket.gets

          response = "Hello World!\n"

          # We need to include the Content-Type and Content-Length headers
          # to let the client know the size and type of data
          # contained in the response. Note that HTTP is whitespace
          # sensitive, and expects each header line to end with CRLF (i.e. "\r\n")
          socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                       "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
                       "Content-Length: #{response.bytesize}\r\n" +
                       "Connection: close\r\n"

          # Print a blank line to separate the header from the response body,
          # as required by the protocol.
          socket.print "\r\n"

          # Print the actual response body, which is just "Hello World!\n"
          socket.print response

          # Close the socket, terminating the connection
          socket.close

      end#do
    end#do
end#do
```

This way the main Thread doesn't block, as the server runs in a separate thread. But, now when I browse to `http://localhost:2345/` I get no return.

How can I run a server in a separate thread?

Important to know is that this script runs in an application that accepts Ruby plugins. So, it's not like the main thread will terminate, causing the sub thread to close to.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

```
require 'socket' # Provides TCPServer and TCPSocket classes

#start the server thread
server_thread = Thread.start do

    # Initialize a TCPServer object that will listen
    # on localhost:2345 for incoming connections.
    server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2345)

    # loop infinitely
    loop do
      puts "Server started"
      # use a seprate thread, acception multiple incoming connections
      Thread.start(server.accept) do |socket|

          # Read the first line of the request (the Request-Line)
          request = socket.gets

          response = "Hello World!\n"

          # We need to include the Content-Type and Content-Length headers
          # to let the client know the size and type of data
          # contained in the response. Note that HTTP is whitespace
          # sensitive, and expects each header line to end with CRLF (i.e. "\r\n")
          socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                       "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
                       "Content-Length: #{response.bytesize}\r\n" +
                       "Connection: close\r\n"

          # Print a blank line to separate the header from the response body,
          # as required by the protocol.
          socket.print "\r\n"

          # Print the actual response body, which is just "Hello World!\n"
          socket.print response

          # Close the socket, terminating the connection
          socket.close

      end#do
    end#do
end#do

spam_thread = Thread.start do
  loop do
    puts "Another thread"
    sleep 1
  end
end

server_thread.join
spam_thread.join
```

It is import to `join` all the threads spawned from the main thread, because every non-joined thread is killed if the main thread finished.In the example everything works because the main thread is in infinite loop that occupies the main thread, in your case the main thread finishes immediatly after you create the server thread.

Comment: Thanks, but that is why I stated: Important to know is that this script runs in an application that accepts Ruby plugins. So, it's not like the main thread will terminate, causing the sub thread to close to. Using a loop will block the main thread, and thus block the host application.

Comment: Can you be more specific about those Ruby plugins, because I am not familiar with the subject.

Comment: The 'host' application has a ruby runtime in which ruby scripts can be loaded. This runtime's process does not terminate. Unless the program is closed... I've noticed however that every thread goes in a sleep state if the user is not interacting with the software (moving mouse, pressing things, ...) and thus blocking the server. I've found a solution to keep updating the main thread. However, I'll mark your sulution as the answer, because in 'normal' ruby, this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: If you give concreate example what you are using as gems, I would be glad to help. I suspect it has something with the UI-thread, it just does waits for events without sleeping and blocks all the other threads.

Comment: What is the format of this scripts and what restrictions and requirements do they have?

Comment: All they have to do is being ruby.. The code example above is a true script.

Comment: You could compare it to running the above script in an IronRuby runtime. The main thread of IronRuby does also never terminate.

Comment: @KenGey what was the solution to your problem?

Comment: @Sven, well, since ruby threads are green threads (only one can run at the same time and the next one is triggered if the current goes in a sleep state) I used a mechanism available in the host application to put the main thread in a sleep state every x ms. A better approach would be to create the server as a c++ ruby extension and use native threads..